# flatpickr webpack import error in react project

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

I'm trying to use `flatpickr("^4.6.3)"` in a react project that uses webpack as the module bundler. I get this error in this code:

```js
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import 'flatpickr/dist/themes/light.css';

function MyComponent() {
  const flatpickerIn = useRef(null);
  const flatpickrOptions = {
    enableTime: true,
    allowInput: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d h:i K"
    // noCalendar: true,
  };
  const inputRefcallback = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null && !flatpickerIn.current) {
      flatpickerIn.current = flatpickr(node, flatpickrOptions);
    }
  }, [flatpickrOptions]);
  return (
    <input
      name="startDate"
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"
      style={{ width: 'auto' }}
      ref={startDateRef}
    />
  )
}
```

```
TypeError: flatpickr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default(...) is not a function
```

One strange fact is that this code works when rendering the component in storybook. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was with the uglify plugin I am using. The error disappeared after I imported `flatpickr` like so:

```
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min';
```